# Writing a custom file format downloader in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

What I'm aiming to do is write something akin to the `File > Download as > *` functionality currently in Google Spreadsheets, but I want it to be in a custom format.

Specifically, I want to turn a spreadsheet of financial transactions into an QIF or OFX file for importing into accounting software. In essence, pushing a button on the UI will download a QIF/OFX version of the currently open spreadsheet.

I have tried the following so far:

- Publishing a service (via implementing `doGet`) that uses `ContentService` to create the custom file and return it as a download using `TextOutput.downloadAsFile()`. This works if I call the endpoint directly using my browser.
- Tried redirecting the browser to the Service's URL via window.location, but that doesn't seem to be available in the context of the App Script.
- Tried using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` to have the front-end (the spreadsheet) have the browser navigate to the URL for the service. This didn't work either (not really surprising).

So, is this the right approach here? How else can I attack this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is what you have to do.

1. Create a UiApp
2. Add a link to the download inside that app.
3. Show the UiInstance on the spreadsheet

It's a little bit bulky, but it seems the be the cleanest solution.

```
function downloadAsWhatever() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createAnchor("Download the file now!", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/[...]/exec"))
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app.setWidth(300).setHeight(150));
}
```

You can set the size of the app to whatever you'd like. I chose to set it smaller so it takes up less space on the Spreadsheet screen.

---

> For now the best way to direct a user to a new page is to create an anchor widget and have them click it. We understand that this is not an ideal user experience, but it should suffice for must use cases.

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1061)

Comment: Seems like the only viable solution. Cheers!